# How relevant is UTF-7 when it comes to parsing emails?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, text-encoding

I recently implemented incoming emails for an application and boy, did I open the gates of hell? Since then every other day an email arrives that makes the app fail in a different way.

One of those things is emails encoded as UTF-7. Most emails come as ASCII, some of the Latin encodings, or thankfully, UTF-8.

Hotmail error messages (like email address doesn't exist or quota exceeded) seem to come as UTF-7. Unfortunately, UTF-7 is not an encoding Ruby understands:

```
> "hello world".encode("utf-8", "utf-7")
Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError: code converter not found (UTF-7 to UTF-8)

> Encoding::UTF_7
 => #<Encoding:UTF-7 (dummy)>
```

My application doesn't crash, it actually handles the email quite well, but it does send me a notification about the potential error.

I spent some time googling and I can't find anyone that implemented the conversion, at least not as a Ruby 1.9.3 Encoding::Converter.

So, my question is, since I never got an email with actual content, from an actual person, in UTF-7, how relevant is that encoding? can I safely ignore it?

Comment: UTF-7 is barely used *anywhere* except for within email protocols like IMAP

Answer (score 9):

The *only* relevant feature of UTF-7 (over UTF-8 for example) is that it's a 7-bit encoding, just like good old ASCII is. That means that it works over a system that is *not* [8-bit clean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean).

The only large-scale system where this even matters today is mail servers (don't ask me why they didn't fix this problem 10-20 years ago, most servers did, but some ostensibly still didn't).

So: UTF-7 will *only* have relevancy in email systems. Everywhere else UTF-8 is the better choice.

Comment: Well, I am parsing emails, most emails are UTF-8, my question is how many emails should I expect as UTF-7.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Charles Salvia's comment, I found a method in the IMAP module that helped:

```
require "net/imap"
Net::IMAP.decode_utf7(mail_body)
```